# my css hasnt been implemented on my login page

Tags: php, css, button, model-view-controller

my login page is not implementing the css i have used for it my code is designed using mvc and php i tried changing background to pink to see if its working but the css isnt working at all

my code isnt complete so dont worry about missing stuff for the form etc but this is login page code.

```
<?php
require APPROOT . '/views/includes/head.php';
?>

<div class="navbar">
    <?php
    require APPROOT . '/views/includes/navigation.php';
    ?>
</div>
    <div class="container-login">
        <div class="wrapper-login">
            <h2>Sign in</h2>

            <form action="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/users/login" method="POST">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username *" name="username">
                <span class="invalidFeedback">
                   <?php echo $data['usernameError']; ?>
                </span>

                <input type="password" placeholder="Password *" name="password">
                <span class="invalidFeedback">
                   <?php echo $data['passwordError']; ?>
                </span>

                <button id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
                <p class="options">Not registered yet? <a href="<?php echo URLROOT;?>/users/register">Create an account!</a> </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my css for the page.

```
    .container-login {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        top: 20%;
    }
    .wrapper-login{
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .wrapper-login input {
        width: 200px;
        height: 26px;
        border: 1px solid #cccccc;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        font-size: 18px;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        margin: 20px auto;
    }
    
    input::placeholder{
        color: #a1a1a1;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    .wrapper-login h2 {
        font-size: 40px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    .btn-submit {
        width: 200px;
        height: 42px;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        background-color: #000000;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    }
    
    #submit:hover {
    
        border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
        background-color: #a1a1a1;
        transition: 0.15s ease-in;
    
    }
```

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta htttp-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Auction System</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/mframe/css/style.css"/>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
```

Comment: You have a class `btn-submit` but have not applied it to your button. Either add `class="btn-submit"` to your button or change `.btn-submit` to `#submit` in your CSS

Comment: its now #submit but still the rest of the page doesnt work its a whole paghe issue no css is working on the page

Comment: Can you show, what is standing in <head> if you right click right on your page and select "show source text"?

Comment: the css isnt changing the page at all for any of it even the font color for h2

Comment: So it's not only the button but the whole CSS is not applied? Hard to tell without seeing how you implement/load your CSS.

Comment: From your other questions, did you change `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>` to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css"/>` as suggested?

Comment: that is my head and yh i have just noticed the css doesnt change anything at all on any of my pages which is annoying

Comment: and yes its /css/style.css

Comment: Does `http://localhost/mframe/css/style.css` exist? Can your browser load it? Are you familiar with your browser devtools/network tab to debug issues like this? Does it get loaded? Any errors in your browser console?

Comment: think i have found issue if i go to the url that the head says is the style sheet its different to the style sheet ive been altering however its the only style sheet i have in directory so not sure how to sort this

Comment: yes it loads i just loaded it but its missing all the new css ive added

Comment: i have fixed it

Comment: i changed the url root

Comment: added /public/css/style instead of urlroot/css